# Sharepoint 2007 - Wheres the approval workflow?

Tags: sharepoint

we've had Sharepoint installed at our business for a few years now, and now were trying to use some workflows.  Unfortunately, the only available workflow template is the "three state workflow".  Online, Ive seen several resources for an "approval" workflow, but I dont see it as an option when creating a new workflow.

Does anyone know if this is something we can download, or have to install separately?  Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

**Edit**: OK, it looks like we have WSS 3.0 installed, and not MOSS 2007.  From what I can gather, the approval workflow isnt available on WSS 3 (can anyone verify this?).  So here's my new question - how do I install a workflow on WSS 3.0?  I found the 2007 Office Developer Resources SDK, and it looks like I have the source code for the approval workflow.. now I just want to jam it on our server, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approval workflow is surely part of MOSS and not WSS that you have. Sorry for you. You can still develop your own workflow though using VS.NET and/or Sharepoint Designer. following may get you started:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101005911033.aspx

http://rshelton.com/archive/2007/10/05/sharepoint-document-workflow-with-visual-studio-workshop-documents-download.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Ashish Patel, those links are helpful, but let me ask this, can I install new workflow templates on WSS 3.0?  Or must I be on MOSS 2007 to install new workflows?

Comment: As far as I know, WSS fully supports Workflow Foundation and the FEATURE/SOLUTION Framework, so you should be able to install new workflow templates

Comment: since we only have WSS, we had to resort to Sharepoint designer.  However after some clicking around, it was fairly simple to do.  Thx!